# Return Partial View with ajax call

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8.1

I want to return a Partial View in ajax  call in Sitecore, I am already using web APIs, i can return JSON object, but i want to return the view with HTML :

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult StoreSearchResultsPartial()
                        {      
                  return PartialView("/views/components/StoreSearchResults.cshtml");
                }
```

my ajax call :

```
  var ajaxUrl = "/api/sitecore/components/StoreSearchResultsPartial"
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: ajaxUrl,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
                $("#searchResults").html(result);
            },
            error: function (result) {

            }
        });
```

i am using web API for other functionalities, so i added my routing :

```
public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
        var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

        RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                        name: "NamedActionApi",
                        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                        ).RouteHandler = new SessionRouteHandler();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiRoute",
                                 "api/{controller}/{id}",
                                 new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });



        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
}
```

When I comment this routing everything is working fine.

Comment: And what's the issue? What happens when you run your code?

Comment: @MarekMusielak: The issue is my action method not getting called, i am getting this error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Is you action inside controller called `ComponentsController`? also you should rename your action call to `public ActionResult StoreSearchResults()` if you use this action name in javascript.

Comment: @MarekMusielak : that was wrong copy, sorry. it is StoreSearchResultsPartial, i found the issue but i don't know how to fix it. i updated my question can you check please

Comment: have a look at the blog posts: http://wp-bartbovendeerdtcom.azurewebsites.net/sitecore-8-webapi-v2-mvc-and-attribute-routing/ and another one here http://cardinalcore.co.uk/2015/03/19/sitecore-webapi-hooking-into-the-route-setup/

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine now, I changed my routing to start with something not "**api**", so i changed this `api/{controller}/{action}/{id}` to be `mywebapi/{controller}/{action}/{id}`, then i was able to call : `/api/sitecore/components/StoreSearchResultsPartial`